# Send a message on Graylog GELF UDP Input through a JAVA class

Tags: udp, gelf, graylog3

I've this **Graylog GELF UDP Input** ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rIMl.jpg)) and I need to send a message through a JAVA class.
The message isn't Log info, but is JSON.
Can you help me find a simple solution?

I already use Graylog with AMQP Input, but I would like to create an emergency solution in case RabbitMQ is not available.
Thanks